# How to avoid React Hook UseState to share the states?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I may have a bad title for this question, but here's my situation.

I use a chunk of json to render a list. The list item can be expanded and showed the sub list if it has children property. The json structure includes two arrays and each array contains more sub-arrays. I use tabs to switch arrays.

I use `useState` to manage the value `isExpanded` of each individual sub-array component. but it seems like the state `isExpaned` is shared for all tabs.

The state `isExpanded` remains same even if I switch to another tab. In other words, why the sub-list keep expanded when I switch to another tab?

In addition, why the expanded sub-list of each tab overlaps each other. They should keep 'close' when I switch to another tab because I set the initial state to `false` already. (`const [isExpand, setIsExpand] = useState(false)`)

```
const ListItem = ({name, children}) => {
  const [subList, setSubList] = useState(null)
  const [isExpand, setIsExpand] = useState(false)
  const handleItemClick = () => {
    children && setIsExpand(!isExpand)
    console.log(isExpand)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    isExpand && children && setSubList(children)
  }, [isExpand, children])
  return (
    <div className='list-wrapper'>
      <div className='list-item'>
        {name}
        {
          children && 
          <span 
            className='expand' 
            onClick={() => handleItemClick()}>
            {isExpand ? '-' : '+'}
          </span>
        }
      </div>
      <div className='list-children'>
        {
          isExpand && subList && subList.map((item, index) => 
            <ListItem key={index} name={item} />
          )
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here's the [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-hodgkin-vfyst), anyone helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like React is confused due to `index` being used as `ListeItem` key.
*(React will try to "share" `isExpanded` state as they look the same according to the key you specified)*

You could change the key from `key={index}`

```
   <div className="contents">
      {contents &&
        contents.children &&
        contents.children.map((item, index) => (
          <ListItem
            ......  ....
            key={index}
            name={item.name}
            children={item.children}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
```

to use more distinct key, `item.name`

```
   <div className="contents">
      {contents &&
        contents.children &&
        contents.children.map(item => (
          <ListItem
            ......  ....
            key={item.name}
            name={item.name}
            children={item.children}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
```

Check out the forked sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/soanswer57212032-9ggzj